# Using an external class not working as expected

Tags: php

I have an issue where I am trying to call a method from a class in another file. I have done: `use Tests\Feature\testName`and this shows the class when I try to use it within my function and even shows the function I am trying to call within the testName file. But, when I try to run just the PHP file I get this error:

`Uncaught Error: Class 'Tests\Feature\testName' not found in path\to\file`

I am a little confused on why it is not working and if someone could explain why this is, I would be very grateful! :)

Comment: *"when I try to run just the PHP file"* ... you have included the other file that contains the class, correct?

Comment: or have you configured a loader?

Comment: Why the downvote? :( Also I have done the `use Tests\Feature\testName` to give me access to it's functions?

Comment: That's not how it works. Either you configure a loader, either you require the file of the class, `use` only allows you to not use the FQDN of the class.

Comment: What do you mean by "configure a loader" could you expand on this?

Comment: You probably want to read this : https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHP, classes are not included simply be using a `use` directive. You need to load them by including the file where the class is.

#### What is the use of `use` ? (haha)

`use` let you not using the FQDN of the class you're using, see the piece of code below :

```
use \A\Long\Namespace\Foo;
$foo = new Foo();
// Without use, you would have needed : $foo = new \A\Long\Namespace\Foo();
```

### The boring way

That's how PHP devs used to do this many years ago, it's just explicitly requiring the file :

```
// Foo.php
class Foo {}

// index.php
require_once( __DIR__ . '/Foo.php');
$foo = new Foo();
```

### The normal way

Now, people use code that automatically load the classes with a pattern, you could use [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) (among others, won't enter an opinion-based discussion here) or, if you project is small and you don't want to use it because you're not confident with it, manually load your classes. For instance, put all your classes in a `class` folder and name the file with the same name of the class, then you can use the following piece of code :

```
spl_autoload_register(function ($class) {
    include 'classes/' . $class . '.class.php';
});
```

To load all the classes you need (you probably want to put this at the beginning of your PHP code).

Comment: thank you for this. This was probably the best explanation! :)